# Expressing the negation of a statement using predicates and quantifiers with conditions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ and $C$ be the subsets of a universal set $U$. Let $A(x)$ denote the predicate "$x\in A$". 
Express the negation of

$$A\subseteq (B\cup C)$$

using quantifiers, the predicates $A(x),B(x)$ and $C(x)$, and logical connectives such that no negation is on the immediate left of

1. a quantifier
2. a statement joined by a logical connective

Attempt at solution:

I ended up with $\exists x\in U(x\in A \land (x\notin B \land x\notin C))$ and am very tempted to just write it as $\exists x\in U(A(x) \land B(x) \land C(x))$ where $B(x)$ denotes "$x\notin B$" and $C(x)$ denotes "$x\notin C$".

Is there any way to express it using $B(x): x\in B$ and $C(x): x\in C$?

Comment: You can get $\land$ with `\land`; `\in` and `\notin` give you $\in$ and $\notin$, respectively, `\subseteq` is $\subseteq$, `\cup` is $\cup$. You’ll find a basic tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks, I've been struggling with the formatting.

Comment: I think that I actually caught everything this time; I just thought that I’d give you a leg up for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions imposed in the statement of the problem allow you to place a negation immediately in front of a simple predicate like $B(x)$, so you can write

$$\exists x\in U\big(A(x)\land\neg B(x)\land\neg C(x)\big)\;.$$

Comment: Ah, right. I did not realize that. Thanks.

Comment: @Guest: You’re welcome. (Basically they just wanted to make sure that you pushed the negation(s) as far inside as possible.)